# Xcode variables view empty values while debugging

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I cannot see the value of variables while debugging my app. I have already checked the build settings and optimization values are set to none, also my Scheme. See screenshots below:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you using mixed code from swift and Objective-C?

Comment: yes, I'm using code from objective-c with bridging header

Comment: maybe you are including wrongly your headers, I was working in a project with the same issue and only reviewing all includes solves the issue

Comment: ok i will get back after i try this

Comment: Is the debug data missing all the time, or only some function calls?

Comment: all the time @TheBasicMind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to remove things from your bridging-header one by one and see if you can narrow down the issue.

I think I read somewhere that if a library is causing many issues behind the scenes, this can stop your debugger working.

In my case 
I was using Facebook Tweaks library

Once I got rid of it, I got my debugging back.

and in my AppDelegate.swift

import Tweaks into the AppDelegate file.

```
 import Tweaks
```

Comment: assuming the bridging-header is the culprit, how do i fix the issues in my briding-header though? It still compiles and i need it.

Comment: import specific file in Appdelegate.

Comment: Hi, I figured it out via removing things one by one. turns out i have a 
`typedef unsigned short WORD;
typedef char* LPCSTR;
typedef unsigned char * LPBYTE;
typedef unsigned long long ULONG;
typedef unsigned char BYTE;`

in my bridging header file and it causes this issue. i don't know why though.

Answer (score 0):

Moved RxSwift library from the Swift package Dependencies to CocoaPod